# mklink gives message "invalid switch"

Tags: windows-10, command-line, symbolic-link, mklink, web-whatsapp

So I'm trying to move Whatsapp Desktop's media folder from `C` drive on Windows 10, where I have limited space, to `E`. I closed Whatsapp (also via the task manager). I moved the media directory to `E`, and now trying to create a link from the existing location in `C`, to the new location in `E` like this:

```
mklink d/ E:/target C:/original
```

No matter what variation I try, I get `Invalid switch E:/target`. Perhaps I got confused between source and target? I tried this:

```
mklink d/ C:/original E:/target
```

And got `Invalid switch C:/original`. I ran the command from cmd prompt with admin privileges. I double checked all paths. I even tried a dummy target path which for sure exists, is empty and the path to it is correct, same result. I tried `/h` instead of `d/`, but keep getting `Invalid switch`.

I previously managed to do a similar action on this computer, creating a link and moving Windows Installer directory to `E`. But can't seem to recreate it due to above snag.

Any further ideas what might be the issue?

Comment: The syntax should be `mklink /d <link> <target>`, not `d/`.

Answer (score 0):

Many older Windows command-line tools, especially those built into cmd.exe (surprisingly MKLINK is indeed built-in and not a mklink.exe), have a peculiar command-line parser that thinks *any* parameter that contains a `/` is an option switch, even if it is not separated from the rest by space – perhaps a relic of the original DEC influence (DCL commands worked the same way).

(For example, `dir Desktop/a` is handled like `dir /a Desktop` and not as `dir Desktop\a`.)

So when you write `E:/target`, mklink thinks you're specifying `E:` as path and `/target` as an option switch. To avoid this, always write paths using Windows-style backslashes whenever dealing with cmd.exe commands, i.e. use `E:\target` instead.

---

Note that the switches are always written as `/d`, **not** `d/`.